# How to read data from GPS gadget

Tags: node.js, encoding, character-encoding, gps

I got unreadable characters from gps. Mby someone know format or how to make it readable. I think it is ASCII. But I dont know.
Some data here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3f6j13mkphp6ti9/rawData.txt?dl=0
Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/4qwq54

Comment: Why do you think that the data are in ASCII? This is for sure not ASCII, dont you see the high number of strange characters ? Ist a binary format, which GPS chip you use?

Comment: I use TK110. Maby it sends wrong data to server, but i configuret it right way.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely looks like some internal encoding. You would need to know how it is created to know how to decode/decrypt it. More information would be nice.